# How to create an Email Account in Kloxo via PHP?

Tags: php, kloxo

I'd like to create email accounts (email@myserver.com) dynamically with PHP, i have a VPS server with HyperVM and Kloxo. I know a solution for Cpanel + Php integration but for kloxo i did not discover .

Comment: "Kloxo" is probably rare enough that it would be useful to hyperlink it in your question.

Comment: Hmm, not very documented: http://wiki.lxcenter.org/JSON+Adding+a+resource

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using the webcommand API as it is unsecure.  (maybe using php sessions it would be alright though).

I do it via PHP exec and call the bash script directly:

```
sh /script/add --parent-class=mmail --parent-name=example.com --class=mailaccount --name=dummy --v-password=123456
```

Some of you may be against using PHP exec();  IMO it can be used safely.

Cheers,
H.

KimeraLive.com